# Access DropBox or Google Drive API from a Web app

Tags: ios, web-applications, browser, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

Apologies if this is a rubbish question, but it's something I've never had to give much thought and I'm short on time.  I have a Web App which is required to run offline and on iOS.  This Web App has a lot of content consisting mainly of videos.  One solution we are thinking of is to utilise DropBox's or Google Drive's API's to download the content and access it.

The main issue with this is whether you can access a native app (DropBox or Google Drive) from a browser or Web App.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Ideas so far are:

- Access Drop Box or Google Drive native app from a web app (not sure if this is possible and is the current question)
- Wrap up the web app to make it a hybrid native app using something like Phone Gap (this is plan B but will have its own issues)
- Convert to a Google Chrome App to get improved access to Google Drive API (not sure how this would function on iOS)
- Start from scratch and build a native iOS app (a longer term solution)

Thanks

Chris

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you ask "whether you can access a native app"? If you need to access file content from accounts on either of these services from your own app, you'll generally want to use the respective API(s). (E.g., for Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/developers  ) That works via communicating with the services servers, and not native apps, which may or may not be installed. Of course, when offline you can't make API calls, but you can cache file content while online. Likewise, native apps won't necessarily have what you need cached.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for you response.  What I mean is can I access the native apps content, so download all content to the phone utilising DropBox.  Then I was hoping the API would allow me access the content that's been downloaded on the phone so I can access it offline.  Sounds like I'm misunderstanding the way the API works if it can only communicate with the services servers and I'm assuming therefore only work online anyway?  I'm in a rush so posing this question at the same time as reading up on the subject!

Comment: That's right. I can only speak with confidence on the Dropbox API, but yes, the Dropbox API enables you to communicate with the Dropbox API servers to upload and download content to and from accounts. On iOS, in order to conserve resources (storage, bandwidth, battery, etc.) the official app doesn't download all content automatically like the desktop app does anyway. iOS itself, especially iOS 8, does offer some native ways for apps to exchange data though, e.g., "Document Provider".

Comment: Short answer: no.   Even if a native app would store data, you could not access that from a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up making a hybrid app using PhoneGap for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Late, but maybe helpful: www.cloudrail.com
It's a useful Javascript library to access the Dropbox and Google Drive API

Comment: Looks like a good product, we ended up making a hybrid app using PhoneGap.